# Did Miriam's well waters cause a need to use bathroom?

Tags: parts-of-the-body, bathroom, miracle, dor-hamidbar

IIRC, the Manna was miraculously and wastelessly absorbed by the body.

Did the water they drank from Miriam's miraculous well also possess miraculous properties and was wasteless or it was regular and caused the need to micturate?

Comment: Take a look at this week’s parsha about covering bodily waste in the Midbar. By the way, welcome back!

Comment: Kidney function is independent of liquid consumption.

Comment: @LN6595 Sorry, what does it mean?

Comment: Urination is necessary regardless of liquid intake. So it would have been necessary regardless.